# Video overlay gradient height spread across the height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my overlay gradient on video to stop at the height of where video ends, but it seem like it is going across all the way. If i do height:auto, it end up at top, My [codepen](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/WROrBN) is here

```
  .graident{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background: linear-gradient(
       45deg, 
       rgba(229, 237, 188, 1), 
       rgba(59, 135, 187, 1));
       opacity:0.90;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      text-align:center;
      z-index:1
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the gradient won't ever know the height of the video. This could be fetched with javascript but if you want refrain from doing so what you'll need to do is moving the gradient div into the video section and remove the absolute positioning of the video element. This allows the video section to get the dimensions of the video element and hence you can set the gradients with and height to the same.

```
<section class="video">
  <section class="graident">
  <h1>This is nav</h1>
</section>
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>

video{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  background:cover
}
.video{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPWaPV

Comment: This is what i wanted, Why wasn't my spreading across the page. It is so hard to understand positions.

Comment: Simply because the parent's height (in this case the body) is what it tries to adjust to when `position: absolute` is set. If a parent element however has `position: relative` then it will adjust according to that instead. Yes, positioning etc. can be a bit confusing to grasp at first.